# How to write convert string to Document object

Tags: android, xml-parsing, sax, android-xml, saxparseexception

I have a string that's has xml content in it like this:

```
String xml = "<item_list>" +
                "<category id='2' name='categoryName'>" +
                   "<item id='41' name='item1' />" +
                "</category>" +
             "</item_list>)";
```

I want to convert this to an Document object. Here my code for doing this:

```
Document doc = null;
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
StringReader sr = new StringReader(xml);
InputSource is = new InputSource(sr);
doc = builder.parse(is);
```

When I run this I get the next error:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected token (position:TEXT )@1:139 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40fa7860)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your xml string as:

```
String xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
                "<item_list>" +
                "<category id='2' name='categoryName'>" +
                   "<item id='41' name='item1' />" +
                "</category>" +
             "</item_list>";
```

Currently you are missing xml document header `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>` in your string

for more help how we create xml doc in android see this tutorial :

http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/android-xml-adventure-create-write-xml-data/

Answer (score 0):

`"</item_list>)";`

That parenthesis shouldn't be there.